# Subgroup of a finitely generated group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is every subgroup of a finitely generated group also finitely generated? And if so does it have the same amount of generators?

Comment: No, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983480/commutator-subgroup-of-rank-2-free-group-is-not-finitely-generated

Comment: absolutely amazing, thank you

Comment: Regarding the second question even if the subgroup is finitely generated it can have fewer generators than the whole group, just take the cyclic group generated by one of them!