# commutator of free group has infinite rank

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

if G is free group of rank >1 , Show that the commutator [G,G] has infinite rank. Please help,
I tried to find an expression of the commutator but I have no idea

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983480/commutator-subgroup-of-rank-2-free-group-is-not-finitely-generated   In particular read the answer by Timbuc and the comment below it

Comment: need for any rank grater than one , not only for rank =2

Comment: Well...if you have it for rank two then you have if for **any** rank bigger than two ....right?