# Cardinality of the space of all subgroups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(G,+)$ be an (abelian) group whose cardinality is $\mathcal{k}$.
What is the size of the space of all subgroups of $G$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971232/can-a-countable-group-have-uncountably-many-subgroups) question suggests that it is possible the answer is $2^{\mathcal{k}}$.

Anyway, my question is concerned only with the case $G=\Bbb{Q}^n$, where $n\ge1$.
And I hope (with few chances) that the cardinality of the set of all its subgroups is exactly $\aleph_0$.

**Edit:** In the previous version of the question, I wrote $G=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/how-to-find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbq for most of the answer to this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all subgroups of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/how-to-find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbq)

Comment: I have changed the question a little bit. Anyway, the accepted answer gives a reference and I have to check the paper. Thank you to both of you :)

Comment: If I understand correctly Theorem 1 of the reference, the set of all subgroups of $\Bbb{Q}$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{N}^{\Bbb{N}}$, i.e. the cardinality of continuum $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: So, for any positive integer $n$, we have that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a lower bound for the size of the set of subgroups of $\Bbb{Q}^n$, and hence it equals $\mathcal{c}$. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Given that the cardinality is infinite, I think that the answer is $2^k$. The cardinality of an infinitely generated group is less or equal to the cardinality of the set of it's generators.  Then you can define an injective function from  $2^S$ to the set of subgroups of $G$ where $S$ is a minimal generating set, such that a vector in $2^S$ is sent to the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elements whose entries in the vector is $1$.
For example if $S=\{ g_1, g_2,g_3,g_4 \}$, then  $(1,0,0,1)\mapsto \langle g_1,g_4\rangle$.

If this argument is correct then $\vert 2^S\vert \leq \vert\mathcal{S}(G) \vert$, where $\mathcal{S}(G)$ is the set of subgroups of $G$. Since $\vert S\vert\geq k$, then $\vert \mathcal{S}(G)\vert \geq 2^k$.

I am using the answer I obtained in this thread: [Cardinality of a generated group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191267/cardinality-of-a-generated-group)

Comment: In this thread, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257175/countable-group-uncountably-many-distinct-subgroup, doesn't Nate Eldrege's answer show that $\mathbb{Q}$ has uncountably many additive subgroups?